# Which tools do you use to collect information when the application is down on the production server

Tags: linux

I have an application(multithreaded) which is developed in C running in the production server. Recently, my application got into the hang state for 5 hours and we could not notice it.

So, we developed a script which alerts us, takes the information about

```
pstack
strace
lsof
gcore
top
full processlist ( for mysql ).
```

and restarts the application.

Hence, we will get a alert as well as the required details why the process got into the hanged stated.

What tools do you use to analyze the problem, when the application is down.

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? Doesn't that depend on your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use **[Monit](http://www.mmonit.com/monit)**.

It's a daemon and process watching utility that can take any number of actions based on an easy human-friendly configuration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug a running application using gdb and strace. These will attach to a running process.